# Projective groups and retraction definitions in Lyndon & Schupp

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

I'm reading *Combinatorial Group Theory* (by Lyndon & Schupp) and on p.2 they define a *projective* group $P$ to be such that, for any groups $G$, $H$ with $\gamma: G\to H$ a *surjective map* and $\pi: P\to H$ any *map*, there exists a *map* $\phi:P\to G$ such that $\gamma\circ \phi=\pi$.

**Question.** Shouldn't "maps" $\gamma, \phi, \pi$ in the above definition all be required to be ***homomorphisms***??

If they are just maps, it seems then we won't be able to prove that projective groups are free groups. Also, in the general category theory, *projective* objects are always defined in terms of morphisms, not just maps. So I'm confused.

Same issue with the definition of ***retract/retraction*** immediately below in that page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BernardPan Thanks a lot. That makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Martin's suggestion, I am copying my comment as an answer here:

---

Yes, they should be group homomorphisms. But you know, the word homomorphism is too long, so many mathematicians prefer to using map only when no serious conflicts occur (especially in many old texts).